# Azure DevOps Server upload Extension programmatically

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to upload a local `.visx` to a Azure DevOps Server.

Currently I have to upload extensions manually over:

```
http://ip:port/_gallery/manage
```

[image]
Is there something similar to the REST API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Azure DevOps Server upload Extension programmatically

There is no such APIs listed directly in the documentation. But we could grab the API through F12 or Fiddler.

As test, I got following API:

```
POST http://xxxxx:8080/tfs/_apis/gallery/extensions?api-version=3.0-preview.1
```

And the request body:

[image]

Then I test it with Postman, it works fine:

[image]

The question is that we have to upload the `.visx` file to Azure DevOps Server manually to get the extensionManifest.

If you do not want to manually get extensionManifest, you can try to generate the extensionManifest body from a `.visx` file:

```
$body = '{{"extensionManifest": "{0}"}}' -f ([Convert]::ToBase64String([IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($visx)))
```

Hope this helps.